# Some questions about Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 questions about Arrays in Java, hope you can spare your time to help me.

**Question 1:**

```
int[] intArray1 = { 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2 };  
int[] intArray2 = { 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2 };

intArray1.equals(intArray2);
```

But it returns false?

**Question 2:**

I run this code:

```
int[] intArray1 = { 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2 };  //2 is duplicated
Arrays.binarySearch(intArray1,2);
```

and it returns -2.

BUT when I remove duplication:

```
int[] intArray3 = { 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7}; // nothing is duplicated
Arrays.binarySearch(intArray1,2);
```

now it returns 2, which is the right one.

I don't know how binary Search in Array deals with duplication which lead to -2?

Comment: binary search works just on sorted arrays!

Comment: The array *must* be sorted for this to work. See docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28byte[],%20byte%29

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after I added Arrays.sort(intArray1); and Arrays.sort(intArray2); the binarySearch does work! But the **equals** is still **false**

Comment: Looks like [Homework], to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding question 1: arrays inherit the default implementation of `equals()` from `Object`, which returns `true` only if the two objects are identical. You can test arrays for equality of contents using:

```
Arrays.equals(intArray1, intArray2);
```

Regarding question 2: Unless the array is sorted, binary search returns unpredictable (and often wrong) results. That it happens to work on a specific unsorted array is a coincidence.

Answer (score 5):

It is normal you get strange results when calling binarySearch on an array that is not sorted.
It is explicit in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29):

> Searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the
>   binary search algorithm. The array must be sorted (as by the sort method,
>   above) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.
>   If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value,
>   there is no guarantee which one will be found.

The `equals` returns `false` as it should: you created two different arrays, and `equals` tells you the two arrays are different, event though their contents are similar. `Arrays.equals` implements the structural comparison you meant to use.

Answer (score 4):

Array objects in Java do not override the `equals()` method. Thus you must use utility method [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29):

```
Arrays.equals(intArray1, intArray2);
```

Binary search only works on [sorted arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29):

```
Arrays.sort(intArray1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 :

In this case `equals` compares objects(i.e. pointers) not their content. You have created two different objects and `equals` returns `false` as expected.

Comment: Not quite, the default implementation of `equals` from `Object` compares pointers. Other classes can overide this.

Comment: @weston - Of course I meant 'In this case, `equals` ...'. Edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Question #1:** The `equals()` method compares the reference of the objects and not the content within the reference as such. Hence the equals() method fails for your case. One way to compare would be use [Arrays.equals(int[] a, int[] a2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29). According to the Javadoc:

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one
>   another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain
>   the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements
>   in the two arrays are equal. Two objects e1 and e2 are considered
>   equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)). In other words, the
>   two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same
>   order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are
>   null.

**Question #2**: From the Javadoc for [binarySearch(int[] a, int key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

> Searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the
>   binary search algorithm. The array must be sorted (as by the
>   sort(int[]) method) prior to making this call. **If it is not sorted,
>   the results are undefined. If the array contains multiple elements
>   with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be
>   found.**

So, you would need an array which is sorted and also without duplicates for this method to work correctly.

Comment: Actually, the relevant method in this case is `Arrays.equals(int[] a, int[] a2)`.

Comment: @TedHopp: I copy-pasted the wrong signature from the Javadoc. Thanks for pointing this out! Edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

**-** First of all binary-search is to be applied on a `sorted array`, thats the reason for the abnormal behaviour.

**-** Secondly,  you should use method `Arrays.equals():`

`Arrays.equals(intArray1, intArray2);`